# How can I look for multiple words in an element, and then have an alert tell me which ones were found?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Greasemonkey newbie here. So essentially, I'm looking to search for specific keywords (maybe, more, everywhere) in an element with text content, and if it finds any 1 or more of those words, I'm trying to have my script repeat back to me which ones it found within an alert message.  I've been finding a whole bunch of solutions through other SO questions that come super close to what I'm looking for, but not exactly the fit I need.

My previous question here dealt with arrays, and I'm back at it again with another array mess.  Here's what I think should work, but no luck just yet. What am I doing wrong?

```
   var keywords = ["maybe","more","everywhere"]
   var searcharea = document.querySelector('#content > div > section > div.hero-body > div > div > div > p')

if(searcharea.innerHTML.indexOf(keywords) !== -1) {
        keywords.forEach(item=> {
    console.log ("Hey! We found the words" + item + "in this message!");
    }
}
```

I'm also been trying to use something like this, would this put me on the right track?

```
var words = searcharea.innerHTML.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```js
var keywords = ["maybe","more","everywhere"]
var searchArea = document.querySelector('#content > div > section > div.hero-body > div > div > div > p')
var searchString = searcharea.innerText

keywords.forEach(keyword => {
  if(searchString.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) 
    console.log(`Found ${keyword}!!`)
})
```

Comment: I would also consider .innerText or textContent instead of innerHTML

Comment: Ah so close! This is definitely the right direction I'm aiming for, thanks so much!  The one thing left now is that for each keyword that's found, a new message will be created for each one.  For right now, it looks like the console will show:

`Found maybe !!
 
Found more !!`
Is there a way I could combine all found keywords into a single alert/console message to say "Found maybe, more !!"

Comment: Well don't I feel silly.  I added `[1]` at the end of the console.log function, and now it works perfectly.  Thanks again so much to both of you!

Comment: Whoops, editing this out since my "fix" didn't quite work out how I intended it to.  My multiple console troubles still remain, hmmm.